# An FileNotFoundException which is already thrown

Tags: java, exception, compiler-errors

I have a small code (a part of the whole) in here for a hangman game and the error it gives while compiling.

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Hangman {

    //Properties

    private final int MAX_TRIES = 6;
    private StringBuffer secretWord; 
    private StringBuffer allLetters;
    private StringBuffer usedLetters;
    private int numberOfIncorrectTries;
    private int maxAllowedIncorrectTries;
    private StringBuffer knownSoFar;

    //Constructor   

    public Hangman() 
    {
        numberOfIncorrectTries = 0;
        maxAllowedIncorrectTries = MAX_TRIES;
        allLetters = new StringBuffer("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
        usedLetters = new StringBuffer("");
        secretWord = chooseSecretWord();          //THIS IS LINE 33
        knownSoFar = new StringBuffer("");

        for (int count = 0; count < secretWord.length(); count++)
        {
            knownSoFar.append("*");
        }
    }


    //Methods

    public StringBuffer chooseSecretWord() throws FileNotFoundException{

        File file = new File("words.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        final int NUMBER_OF_WORDS;
        int counter;
        int wordIndex;

        NUMBER_OF_WORDS = 99;

        StringBuffer[] words = new StringBuffer[NUMBER_OF_WORDS];

        //move all words to words array
        counter = 0; 
        while(scanner.hasNext())
        {
            StringBuffer newWord = new StringBuffer(scanner.next());
            words[counter++] = newWord;
        }
        //Find a random integer to get random index of array
        wordIndex = (int)(Math.random()*NUMBER_OF_WORDS);

        return words[wordIndex];
    }
```

Error:

```
1 error found:
File: E:\Java\homeworks\Hangman\Hangman.java  [line: 33]
Error: unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

I am trying to find the reason for an hour, but wasn't able to see anything. words.txt file is in the same folder with the program and chooseSecretWord() method worked in a main function (which is built to test it). I am suspecting that it is a PATH problem, but not sure how to fix it. Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: It is a compilation error. Nothing to do with PATH whatsoever. You need to learn about the distinction between compilation and runtime.

Comment: As a beginner, i can't think of anything else right now.

Comment: Nonsense. PATH problems prevent you from executing Java. They do not cause compilation errors. All the information you need is right there in he error message. You don't need to dream up irrelevant explanations, and even as a beginner you need to have more than one thought in your head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FileNotFoundException is a checked exception which means that you need to catch or throw it. It is up to your design if you are going to throw or catch, but it needs to be done somewhere.

So you can throw here:

```
public Hangman() throws FileNotFoundException
```

Or catch here:

```
allLetters = new StringBuffer("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
usedLetters = new StringBuffer("");
try {
    secretWord = chooseSecretWord();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Do something here, example log the error our present a error message to the user.
}          //THIS IS LINE 33
knownSoFar = new StringBuffer("");
```

If you want to know more about exceptions; then, docs.oracle.com has an excellent tutorial about exceptions:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html

Comment: Ah, but it solved! I didn't know that constructors also needed that kind of thing. Thanks!

Comment: @MaciejCygan You are mistaken.

Comment: @EJP Yes apoogies :), I was still having the exception for some reason on my test bed. Upvoted

Answer (score 1):

you throw an FileNotFoundException in method chooseSecretWord(). and use the method in constrouctor.so you must do it :

```
public Hangman() throws FileNotFoundException{
     ....
}
```

or catch it in constrouctor.